# Non docketing of response to examiner

Tags: office-action

This refers to my application no 14/378346 with USPTO.

After first RCE, Office action was mailed to me on 06 December, 2017. I sent response on 02 February, 2018 which was duly acknowledged. But the same has not been docketed to examiner till date (23 Feb,2018). Confirmed from Private PAIR and the examiner. Previously, docketing to examiner used to be done in two to three days. Hardly ten days are left for expiry of response period.

My Question is: i) What could be the reason for non docketing? iii) What can I do to find out exact present status ? iii) If I do not get response before 06 March, 2018; do I have to apply for extension of time?

Comment: It looks like your dates may have typos in them.

Comment: Do you have proof it reached the uspto? As another question for all, would resending it be a problem?

Comment: @ George White. Thanks for pointing out typos. Sheer tension prevailed. @DonQuiKong. Yes, I have proof. As mentioned, I have acknowledgement with EFS ID. Besides, PAIR image file wrapper shows my response. Transaction history in PAIR does not show "Forwarded to Examiner". Also confirmed from the Examiner that the response has not been docketed to him.

Comment: Call to the examiner.

Comment: @MikkPutk As simple as this response is, it is a reasonable answer and should be submitted as one. The moderator here hates anything close to an answer in comments.

Comment: Seems like op already did that. I have no expirience with this but if you submitted the response in time everything should be fine (in my opinion). I don't see any reason how it would be your problem if the office works slow. I hope someone can confirm this in an answer. But I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question should not be when will it be forwarded to the examiner but if there is any bureaucratic reason why it might not be considered as a properly submitted responsive document as of the date you uploaded it. A properly submitted response stops the clock. It doesn't matter if it is held up being forwarded to the examimer.

Call or otherwise contact the [USPTO Application Assistance Unit.](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/application-assistance-unit-aau)  If that doesn't work, you can call the examiner's supervisor. I looked up your application and, as you say, it is clear that the documents are in PAIR. I see that you signed it, so that should not be the problem, but if the administrative people do not think a response is signed, then the response hasn't really occured - even though it is in PAIR.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call to the examiner. Under "Conclusions" of the Office Action you should find examiner's contact number.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in my question and comments, that option is already exercised. The examiner does not know when my response will be docketed to him. Is there any other option left ?